# Android monitor does show files

Tags: android, android-studio, android-monitor

I am working on a DBMS project in Android using **SQLite** I want to see the database after its creation in the Data/data folder in Android monitor. I am using rooted Android device for running my app. I am unable to see the app files in Android monitor I have searched solutions for this issue every solution says open Android monitor but when I open Android monitor I am unable to see files. thanks for your help. I have tries `tools->android->android monitor` but it did not work.

[I have uploaded a Screenshot of Android monitor in my Android Studios](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DVent.png)

Answer (score 0):

Go to ../platform-tools folder and follow following steps:

```
1. adb shell
2. run-as com.your.package
3. ls -> You would see the databases here.
4. cp /data/data/com.your.package/databases/you-db-name  /sdcard/file_to_write"
```

You don't even need the rooted device for this.